# Having trouble plucking the correct value from my DB

Tags: c#, sql, database

Sorry for not putting the question in the title, the real problem is that I can't see an issue with my code but it's not producing what I want it to.

So I've written some code which is meant to take the database's Password field and inspect its value then store that value as a string within a password variable. In SQL Management studio the value is 'MyPass', that's what I'm expecting to get when I print out the password variable as a MessageBox. Instead I get two boxes, 'password' and then 'password123'. The only column within the table: Login, is one called Password.

Here is the using statement:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT Password FROM LoginInfo"; 
            con.Open(); 

            //SqlCommand to be executed against my DB with the query text and the connection object. 
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            //Sends CommandText to connection. Creates a 
            SqlDataReader read = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); 

            while(read.Read())
            {
                //Convert read to IDataRecord.
                ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)read);  

            }
            read.Close(); 

        }
```

I apologize if my comments are incorrect, I wrote them down because they help me think.

You can read my interpretation of the code below and tell me what's wrong with my thinking process or you can just scour the code samples for errors.

My Interpretation (If you'll indulge me):

So, in the using statement we create a connection, a query string, an SqlCommand and an SqlDataReader. Passing the SqlCommand the query string and the connection object we then set its instance equal to an SqlDataReader, named 'read' with the method ExecuteReader() which takes the command text to wherever the connection is through the connection object.

Next we use a while loop, we use the .Read() to advance the reader on to the first record, since my db only has one record 'Password' this just moves it on to that. Within while we have the method ReadSingleRow which converts the reader instance into an IDataRecord: ((IDataRecord)read).

The ReadSingleRow method:

```
public void ReadSingleRow(IDataRecord record)
    {  
    UserPass = record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("Password"));


      MessageBox.Show(UserPass);
    }
```

the IDataRecord retrieves the string value of the oridinal(ID) password. My understanding is that it looks at the value of Password: Mypass, and then stores that within the UserPass string variable. The MessageBox of course blurts out the variable as a test to see if it worked. It didn't.

So my question is the annoying: why didn't this work? Perhaps I am miss-using the IDataRecord.

Comment: First of all, I have to administer the mandatory lecture about storing passwords in plain text in a database.  BAD!!  Now that that's out of the way -- it seems like you actually have two records, not just one.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still learning, perhaps I should pay more attention to security.

Comment: Is your database SQL Express or some other local database?  It's possible that the database you're actually querying at run-time is not the same one you're querying with SSMS.

Comment: It's SQL Express and I was able to connect with it from VS2013 Ult, wouldn't it throw an exception if it didn't connect to the one I asked it to? How can I be sure?

Comment: Just fyi Entity Framework makes working with dbs much, much easier after the initial learning curve

Comment: Thanks reggae I'll look it up.

Comment: Post the value of `connectionString`. Obfuscate any password you might have.

Comment: Dour High Arch, can I ask what you mean? You want the value of my connection string? How would it obfuscate my password?

Comment: @user3752329 They mean remember to hide your password (if there is one) in the connection string before sharing it. Replace the password with something bogus so everyone on stackoverflow doesn't know it.